# Disable http Expect100Continue

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am making a POST request with `RestSharp` and I want to disable a return code of `100`. I set it to `false` in my restOptions but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var restOptions = new RestClientOptions(url)
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
    Expect100Continue = false
};
var client = new RestClient(restOptions);

var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Get);
try
{
    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    return Int32.Parse(response.Content);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```